# Is it better to have just one OData dataSource?

Tags: odata, sapui5

My app's controllers mostly call one dataSource with no issues.

One of them, however uses three seperate datasources, and sometime returns 403 Forbidden errors when accessing them.

```json
"dataSources": {
  "ZSV_SURVEY_SRV": {
    "uri": "/SAPUI5-ABAP-SFI/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSV_SURVEY_SR/",
    "type": "OData",
    "settings": {
      "odataVersion": "2.0",
      "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
    }
  },
  "ZRUI_COMMON_SRV": {
    "uri": "/SAPUI5-ABAP-SFI/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZRUI_COMMON_SRV/",
    "type": "OData",
    "settings": {
      "odataVersion": "2.0",
      "localUri": "localService/ZRUI_COMMON_SRV/metadata.xml"
    }
  },
  "ZTC_SHOP_TRADING_CALENDAR_SRV": {
    "uri": "/SAPUI5-ABAP-SFI/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZTC_SHOP_TRADING_CALENDAR_SRV/",
    "type": "OData",
    "settings": {
      "odataVersion": "2.0",
      "localUri": "localService/ZTC_SHOP_TRADING_CALENDAR_SRV/metadata.xml"
    }
  }
}
```

Would it be better to incorporate the methods all into one dataSource (e.g. `ZSV_SURVEY_SRV`? Or should three separate dataSources be fine and present no problems?

If three dataSources are fine, why do I sometime get the `403` error?

Is there a performance advantage either way?

Comment: Interesting find. I do also have this problem with a project where I added two datasources. The second one fails with Forbidden 403 on the first request I send. When I refresh the page and try it again then it works. I haven't done a lot of research there yet, but if you find something I would be happy if you could give a small update.

Comment: Yes, after a refresh it does work fine, but it shouldn't be happening at all. I'll update if I get an answer.

Comment: How exactly does that one controller use the three data sources? And when exactly do you get *403*? While reading metadata, entity, or collection? Usually, it's recommended to have [one OData service for one Fiori app](https://github.com/rogerxu/rogerxu.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2015-07-02-fiori.md#10-golden-rules-for-fiori-development) (See `4.`).

Comment: I get the 403's on the initial metadata read

Comment: Does this 403 error happen in Web IDE in the cloud or after deploying the app to your on premise system? If it's in the cloud I would double check SAP Cloud Connector and consider reporting an issue to SAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the 403 Forbidden error you are facing, having everything in the same service has its advantages:

Design perspective

1. OData supports multiple data sources inside the same service
   (entity sets)
2. You can easily implement navigation properties
   between your entities
3. You will need just one ODataModel instance
   inside your UI5 app
4. There is no need to implement Promises or any
   other mechanism to make sure that all services are loaded
   successfully
5. There would be no need to use complex bindings in
   UI5 taking data from two different models
6. It's easy to imagine
   that a particular property should is present in more that one OData
   services. It's also possible to believe that you might also have
   errors due to inconsistencies between them (length, precision,
   scale, annotations, etc)

Performance perspective

1. As there would be only one metadata, there would be one only roundtrip to get it
2. The changes of having your metadata cached for all services is smaller

There are definitely more reason for using just one service. As a general rule a Fiori app uses only on service. Also, this service is only used by the Fiori app mentioned. This makes maintenance way easier.

Of course there are exceptions for that, specially when it comes to annotation services.

If you really need three different services for a good reason consider as well creating a 4th one combining all three. In SEGW you can combine other services inside a project by right-clicking in Data Model folder and using *Include >> OData Service (GW)* option

But in any case make use of different entity sets in the same service. It's worth it.

Comment: Completely agree... Manage more than one OData model is a headache... for me the best advantages of a single OData model is the control, in its simplest way, of `dataRequested`, `change` and `dataReceived` events and the error handling with `metadataFailed` and `requestFailed` events.