# Issue with multiple OData services

Tags: sapui5

My app has three OData services.

I've observed a strange behavior.

In first load, one specific data source is not triggered when I call it.

However, when I refresh my app, it works fine.

I've tried to replace the not working source with another OData service, but the same issue happens.

The issue is quite similar to the question [Is it better to have just one oData dataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510049/is-it-better-to-have-just-one-odata-datasource) but I don't get any error 403.

Comment: What did you do to find the issue? How does the corresponding code look like? What can you see in the console of your browser and what in the network tab of your browser’s dev tools? Do you create the ODataModel by hand or via app descriptor?  Please post the manifest.json file! If you don’t offer enough information it will be hard to help you! And where is the question?

Comment: Hi @Nabi, I find that it does not call one specific when I load the app first time. BUT when refreshing the page, it works fine.
In console, no error and network doesn't show any request to backend for that service.
I create model via app descriptor. However, I've tried to create via ODataModel in component, but the same issue.
Here is what I declare in descriptor:
https://imgur.com/a/rE1HZ
https://imgur.com/a/PIfSY
My question is: Why it behaves like this? Is it not able to include more than 3 models?
Thanks

Comment: By the way, I did not downvote the question. To the person who downvoted: I believe adding a reason for a downvote is reasonably fair. Only this way new members can learn, i.e. to post better questions.

Comment: You can have as many ODataModels as you wish (although  a best practice to have 1 for different reasons). So that’s not the issue. Also, you still need to add details: models section of your manifest, you Component.js,... also, please avoid adding the details in the comments section. Instead, update your questions with well formatted code and maybe screenshots. This way you help others to help you.

Comment: Hi Nabi, thank you for your response.
My colleague has figured out the reason.
oData service was not set to use alternate login procedure (SAML removed)
Thank you for your time.